# Bash: read input available (was any key hit?)

Tags: bash, unix, nonblocking, stty

## Question

I am using Bash 5 and have a long-running loop which needs to check occasionally for various keys the user may have hit. I know how to do this using `stty` — see my answer below — but it's more ugly than ought.

Essentially, I'm looking for a clean way to do this:

```sh
keyhit-p() {
  if "read -n1 would block"; then
    return false
  else
    return true
  fi
}
```

#### Non-solution: read -t 0

I have read the `bash` manual and know about `read -t 0`. That does not do what I want, which is to detect if *any* input is available. Instead, it only returns true if the user hits ENTER (a complete line of input).

For example:

```sh
while true; do
  if read -n1 -t0; then
    echo "This only works if you hit enter"
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Although it would make sense, note that adding `-n1` did not help to notify bash that I plan to read a character at a time instead of line-by-line. Perhaps this should be a bash feature request?

Comment: What do you mean **ugly**?

Comment: "Ugly" as in "saving the stty state in a variable and then hoping to restore it before the user hits ^C, leaving their terminal borked".  It should be an atomic action. I know I could `trap EXIT 'stty sane'`, but that makes presumptions about the user's terminal that aren't always valid.

Answer (score 2):

## A working answer, albeit ugly

While the following works, I am hoping someone has a better answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Reset terminal's stty to previous values on exit.
trap 'stty $(stty --save)' EXIT

keyhit-p() {
    # Return true if input is available on stdin (any key has been hit).
    local sttysave=$(stty --save)
    stty -icanon min 1 time 0   # ⎫
    read -t0                    # ⎬ Ugly: This ought to be atomic so the
    local status=$?             # ⎪ terminal's stty is always restored.
    stty $sttysave              # ⎭
    return $status
}

while true; do
    echo -n .
    if ! keyhit-p; then
        continue
    else
        while keyhit-p; do
            read -n1
            echo Key: $REPLY
        done
        break
    fi
done
```

This alters the user's terminal settings (stty) before the `read` and attempts to write them back afterward, but does so non-atomically. It's possible for the script to get interrupted and leave the user's terminal in an incorrect state. I'd like to see an answer which solves that problem, ideally using only the tools built in to bash.

## A faster, even uglier answer

Another flaw in the above routine is that it takes a lot of CPU time trying to get everything right. It requires calling an external program (`stty`) three times just to check that nothing has happened. Forks can be expensive in loops. If we dispense with correctness, we can get a routine that runs two orders of magnitude (256×) faster.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reset terminal's stty to previous values on exit.
trap 'stty $(stty --save)' EXIT

# Set one character at a time input for the whole script.
stty -icanon min 1 time 0

while true; do
    echo -n .
    # We save time by presuming `read -t0` no longer waits for lines.
    # This may cause problems and can be wrong, for example, with ^Z.
    if ! read -t0; then
        continue
    else
        while read -t0; do
            read -n1
            echo Key: $REPLY
        done
        break
    fi
done
```

Instead of changing to non-canonical mode only during the read test, this script sets it once at the beginning and uses an exception handler when the script exits to undo it.

While I like that the code looks cleaner, the atomicity flaw of the original version is exacerbated because the SUSPEND signal isn't handled. If the user's shell is bash, icanon is enabled when the process is suspended, but NOT disabled when the process is foregrounded. That makes `read -t0` return FALSE even when keys (other than Enter) are hit. Other user shells may not enable icanon on ^Z as bash does, but that's even worse as entering commands will no longer work as usual.

Additionally, requiring non-canonical mode to be left on all the time may cause other problems as the script gets longer than this trivial example. It is not documented how non-canonical mode is supposed to affect `read` and other bash built-ins. It seems to work in my tests, but will it always? Chances of running into problems would multiply when calling — or being called by — external programs. Maybe there would be no issues, but it would require tedious testing.